# Plain form ~다 used one after another.

Tags: grammar

I was looking up 굴러다니다 and came around this definition.

구르며 왔다 갔다 하다.

Is it the shortened form of this sentence?

구르며 왔다가 갔다고 하다.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your inquiry,

**"왔다 갔다"** loosely translates to ***"comes and goes"***

Therefore **"왔다 갔다 하다"** would be seen as a verb.

For the most part you would use these terms where something is coming or going a short distance repeatedly. In short if someone was pacing around back and forth.

On the other hand, **"굴러다니다"** has the literal meaning of "***to roll pacing around"***
that is if you were to use it in its adjective form, **"굴러다니는"**

As for the this adjective form, please let me elaborate for better clarity.

For example:

If you were to be in abundance of something, let's for this instance lets say its money.

You are living the life of **Silver Spoon Steve**, and someone who wasn't as fortunate as you came to inquire about some cash.

In this instance you could give the cash freely for the simple fact that there is such an abundance of it. Or the more obvious explanation, ***"Your literally rolling around in money"***

In contrast, If you where to label something or someone as being **"굴러다니는 ..."**, 
consequently you would be implying that this thing is something of little importance.

You don't wouldn't want to give something that is considered to be **"굴러다니는"** as a gift.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I was more curious about "왔다 갔다 하다". This must be an abbreviated form. What is its full form? Is it alright for me to assume that when plain form is used consecutively, it is joined by grammar "다가"?

Comment: It's not really an abbreviated form, but it's using ~다(가) (not plain form) to show that one action stopped and another one happened. With 왔다갔다하다, it transformed into it's own new compound verb, but I wouldn't really consider that an abbreviation.

Comment: @vongola I think that's just how 왔다 & 갔다 are used commonly to mean *to come and go*, it's not an abbreviation or a new word in itself